# How can I efficiently sort a large dataset in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, sorting, data-structures

I'm working on a project where I need to sort a large dataset in Python efficiently. The dataset contains millions of records, and I'm currently using the built-in **`sorted()`** function. However, I'm experiencing performance issues, and the sorting process is taking a significant amount of time.

I've looked into alternatives like **`heapq`**, **`numpy`**, and external sorting algorithms, but I'm unsure about the best approach given the size of my dataset.

Could someone please provide recommendations or examples of efficient sorting techniques in Python for handling large datasets? Additionally, any insights on optimizing memory usage during the sorting process would be greatly

Comment: `sorted` use an algorithm which is already optimized and supposed to be fast even for large datasets (good complexity). There are certainly faster solutions than using it (since it is working with pure CPython objects), but most are not general purpose. Thus, you need to tell us more about the actual real-world problem (not a generic one). A critical information is what are actually the records? How big they are? What field do you want to sort? What is the target machine? Are you limited by the amount of RAM already? Etc.

Comment: If you need to repeatedly sort the data set while processing, and you don't need the whole sorted collection at every intermediate state (but maybe only the first few sorted items), then you might need to look at a different algorithm. Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

**edit: After benchmarking in the provided response I got that multiprocessing slows down the sorting.**

If you are using the built-in functions it means your data fits into memory.

Without knowing the data or if it is possible to process it to speed up the sorting I'd say you could use a parallel process to boost your performance when sorting an extremely large dataset.

Below, there is an approach to sort in parallel using the bulti-in Python packages:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
from random import sample
import heapq


def sort_chunk(chunk):
    return sorted(chunk)


def chunked_list(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]


def parallel_sort(lst, num_processes=None):
    if num_processes is None:
        num_processes = os.cpu_count() or 1

    chunk_size = len(lst) // num_processes
    chunks = list(chunked_list(lst, chunk_size))

    with Pool(processes=num_processes) as pool:
        sorted_chunks = pool.map(sort_chunk, chunks)

    return list(heapq.merge(*sorted_chunks))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    large_list = sample(range(1000000), 100000)
    sorted_list = parallel_sort(large_list)
    print(sorted_list[:10]) # If you would like to see all the output remove the array slice
```

Comment: Is that actually faster? What's your `num_processes` and what are your times for `sorted_list = parallel_sort(large_list)` and for `sorted_list = sorted(large_list)`?

Comment: Pickling/unpickling and inter-process communication can be actually significantly more expensive than sorting data. That being said, this is very dependent of the actual dataset being sorted and the target platform (CPU architecture, RAM and OS). On top of that, I expect `heapq.merge` to be slow and the bottleneck here (sequential expensive part using a pure-Python generator). So slow that `sorted` should be actually often faster.

Comment: You are right, using multiprocessing does not speed up. I used cProfile to benchmark the solution and got the results: 
         214981 function calls (214607 primitive calls) in 0.111 seconds
         5 function calls in 0.027 seconds

The first, with more function calls, is the one using multiprocessing.

I'll edit the response.